# Adding external DLL to source control in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, visual-studio-2015

I am using an external DLL in my web application. I am using VS2015, the DLL does not appear in the pending changes window.

How would I be able to add my external DLL to source control? Do I have to do this manually somehow?

Comment: You normally *do not* add binary files to a source control system. They don't version well. If you insist on doing this anyway, you will probably need to remove some form of `*.dll` pattern from your ignore file. Can't give any more details because you don't tell us which type of source control plug-in you're using.

Comment: I'm using the built in VS2015 source control. I think it's Team Foundation server! If I pull my solution on to my other PC, I would like the external DLL to be there.